# google sheets query = true

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

i'm trying to do a query of baseball play-by-play scoring descriptions. I'm able to get the data of specific columns, but can't filter "isScoringPlay" = true. It's coming up blank in my query. My formula should be:

```
=QUERY(filteredplaybyplay, "SELECT B, C, D, E, G, H WHERE H = 'true'",1)
```

Here's my [range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we8dl.png) and then the [query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4oFq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try shorter:

```
=QUERY(playbyplay, "select B,C,D,E,G,H where H is null", 1)
```

[image]

or proper:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(""&playbyplay, 
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col7,Col8 where Col8 = 'true'", 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Both came up #N/A: Query completed with an empty output.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Thanks for your help!  One tab is the data that shows 'true' and the other has the query where it comes out blank. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wDYZ8sIWkW6NML4H-BJjx66WNhql_Qopoo5Pdj3eCwM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks so much! Any reason why that works and not the original replies?

Comment: query has a nasty behavior when it tries to predict what is the input and based majority of dataset it outputs stuff that may look different than expected. very common issue if majority of cells are text and minority are numeric numbers then it will commit those numeric numbers and vice versa. in your case you had there bolean `FALSE` with plain text `true`. majority was bolean `FALSE` so the plain text `true` got ommited

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the explanation. Figured it had something to do with my non-programming skills of the formatting of FALSE and true. Thanks again!